# yowsup: how to read and process with PHP the received messages?

Tags: php, whatsapp, yowsup

Since WhatsAPI/Chat-API is no longer maintained, I'm trying to understand how to interact with yowsup **from PHP**.

Sending messages is easy with `exec()` and CLI is easy: `yowsup-cli demos --send 39xxx "Test message" --config yowsup.txt` did the trick.

Reading the message **from PHP** is where I'm swamped at. The CLI echo client works as expected with `yowsup-cli demos --echo --config yowsup.txt`, but I need to ingest the number+message sent in my PHP script instead of echoing.

[The doc](https://github.com/tgalal/yowsup/wiki/yowsup-cli-2.0) is lacking in this regard, and I've only a minor Python experience.

So... **how can I read and process with PHP yowsup received messages?**

Answer (score 0):

Start with `./yowsup-cli demos -y -c config.text` and type /L to login. Now you have a real-time send and receive interface for text, voice, video and files with said data transmits and receipts time-stamped, lablelled and addressed to and from your chat partner. Check out the Chat-API project on GitHub re designing a wrapper (PHP, Java, Ruby, whatever) for the protocol...

Comment: I asked about ingesting via PHP, you reply with instruction for the the interactive mode + ChatAPI (which I'm not using). So: how does this anwser the question?